# Getting empty fields in db when posted the room

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have posted a room the room is getting posted in data base perfectly with changing the Booked status as true.
But the remaining added fields like customer name,date, start time and end time fields are added but those fields are empty in database. (Note: using mongodb).

```js
router.post('/booking',async(req,res)=>{
  await client.connect()
  try{
    data={
      customerName:"",
      date:"", 
      startTime:"",
      endTime:"",
      room_ID:""
    }
    const db =await client.db(dbName)
    let requests = await db.collection('RoomCreation').find({room_ID:req.body.room_ID}).toArray();//Getting the data
    console.log(requests)
    
    if(requests[0].Booked_Status===true){
      res.send({
        statusCode:400,
        message:"Room is full"
      })
    }
    else{
      let postroom=await db.collection('roombook').insertOne(req.body);//In another collection making entries
      let room=await db.collection("RoomCreation").findOneAndUpdate({room_ID:req.body.room_ID},{$set:{Booked_Status:true,customerName:req.body.customerName,date:req.body.date,startTime:req.body.startTime,endTime:req.body.endTime}}) //Updating the fields in main collection
      console.log(room)
      res.send({
        statusCode:200,
        data:room,
        data:postroom,
        message:"Room is created for you succesfully"
      })
    } 
   
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
    res.send({
      statusCode:500,
      message:"Internal Server Error",
      booked:false,
      error
    })
  }
  finally{
    client.close()
  }        
})
```

I/P:

```json
{
"Customer_Name":"kranthi",
"Date":"03-01-2022",
"Start_Time":"19:00",
"End_Time":"23:00",
"room_ID":"201"
}
```

O/P in MongoDB:

```
_id:6340d27d827a4536d5b0a952
room_ID:"201"
Seats_Available:5
Amenities
Array
Price:"8000"
Booked_Status:true
customerName:null
date:null
endTime:null
startTime:null
```

Comment: Looks like a fieldname mismatch `req.body.customerName` probably doesn't match the `Customer_Name` in the data.

Comment: In data base there were no fileds when for that document before. I am adding the fields after the booking status became true

Comment: Exactly, if the req object has the body you noted as `I/P`, then `req.body.Customer_Name` will be kranthi, and `req.body.customerName` will be undefined. When the update object includes `customerName:req.body.customerName` that explicitly sets `customerName` to `null`.

Comment: Yes solved my query

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Joe, you should write:

```
let room = await db.collection('RoomCreation').findOneAndUpdate(
  { room_ID: req.body.room_ID },
  {
    $set: {
      Booked_Status: true,
      customerName: req.body.Customer_Name,
      date: req.body.Date,
      startTime: req.body.Start_Time,
      endTime: req.body.End_Time,
    },
  },{
    returnNewDocument: true
  }
);
```